# WinForm genera archivo en ruta equivocada

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa windows forms C# para que abra automáticamente dos aplicaciones del mismo tipo (windows forms), el problema que tengo es que las aplicaciones que se abren crean un archivo txt que es un log y ese archivo ahora me lo genera en la carpeta donde tengo mi programa para abrir las aplicaciones automáticamente y no en la carpeta donde está ubicado el exe de mis dos aplicaciones. Revisando la ruta donde crea el archivo txt del log mis dos aplicaciones veo que la ruta la obtengo mediante

> Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Así se crea el log en mis dos aplicaciones que quiero abrir con mi programa.

```
private void EscribeArchivoLog()
{
    DateTime fchLog;
    DateTime fchMensaje;
    string Directorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Log";
    if (!Directory.Exists(Directorio))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Directorio);
    string mensaje = "";
    int totLog = lstLog.Count;
    StreamWriter swBitComm = null;
    FileStream fil;

    for (int i = 0; i < totLog; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lstLog.Count == 0)
                break;

            mensaje = lstLog[0];

            fchMensaje = Convert.ToDateTime(mensaje.Substring(0, 19));

            if (!File.Exists(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog))
            {
                swBitComm = File.CreateText(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog);
                swBitComm.Close();
                fchLog = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
                fchLog = File.GetLastWriteTime(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog);

            if (fchLog.Date != fchMensaje.Date)
            {
                Program.MoverArchivo(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog, Directorio + "\\" + fchLog.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + nombreArchivoLog);
                swBitComm = File.CreateText(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog);
                swBitComm.Close();
                fchLog = DateTime.Now;
            }

            fil = File.Open(Directorio + "\\" + nombreArchivoLog, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
            fil.Position = fil.Length;
            swBitComm = new StreamWriter(fil);
            swBitComm.WriteLine(mensaje);
            swBitComm.Close();
            swBitComm = null;
            fil.Close();
            fil = null;
            lstLog.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }

    }
    if (lstLog == null)
        lstLog = new List<string>();
}
```

Parece que esa instrucción es la que me está dando ese problema de poner el log en la carpeta actual y no en su respectiva carpeta.

¿Saben cómo puedo hacer para que el log se siga generando en la carpeta donde están los exe de mis dos aplicaciones y no en mi carpeta donde ejecuto mi aplicación para abrir mis formularios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes razón, el problema es que el getcurrentDirectory está cogiendo donde se ejecuta, no donde está el EXE. Tienes diferentes formas para cogerlo, aquí van dos:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Log"
```

El primero puedes coger el directorio base del exe.

```
   string Directorio= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        Directorio = Directorio.Substring(0,Directorio.LastIndexOf('\\')) + "\\Log";
```

El segundo es donde está localizado el exe cogiéndolo del manifest.

Estas dos opciones, incluso si lo mueves se actualizará personalmente prefiero la primera, ya que se adecua más a lo que pides.

Copia de las pruebas realizadas (Borrando datos personales, por eso no está en imágenes):

**Llamar exe a traves de otro programa:**

```
Manifest: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Log

BaseDirectory: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Log

Original: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test2\bin\Debug\Log
```

**Desde el exe:**

```
Manifest: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Log

BaseDirectory: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Log

Original: C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Log
```

Comment: gracias, si es lo que necesitaba y no sabia como realizarlo